# following in linkedin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, linkedin-api

I am developing app integrating linkedin with it.I want to get following (i.e. profile/following).But using

code :

```
@client=@clients.profile(:fields => ["id","pictureUrl","firstName","lastName","headline","following","suggestions"])
```

But it is giving only companies that I am following not the person.Can anyone please help after adding which field I wil get that persons.

Thanks in advance.